# Адаптив под все мониторы

Tags: html, css

Товарищи, когда вы верстаете адаптив, то от каких разрешений монитора вы отталкиваетесь ? если это full hd ,то явно не 1920х1080. Подскажите.
Моя проблема в том, что сайт делиться на 4 части и эти части по 100% высоты монитора и при сужении, например, до 1450х1050 контент вылазит за пределы блока. Под какие точные разрешения верстать и какие инструменты можете посоветовать ?

Answer (score 1):

В адаптивной верстке опираются на ширину дисплея. Подстраиваться под высоту не имеет значения, так как непомещающийся в высоту контент просто скроллится, как и страница в целом.

По ширине я люблю опираться на [брейкпоинты бутстрапа](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints). Вот они:

```
все, что меньше < 480px < 768px < 992px < 1200px < все, что больше
```

Их достаточно, чтобы, с некоторой долей шероховатостей - без проблем адаптировать сайты под разные устройства.

Comment: Если задать 100% высоты блока ( а за этим блоком идет еще один блок 100% высоты ), то контент первого начинает вылазить на второй или ( если задан overflow:hidden ), то понятно что происходит